# How do i call a random integer between 1-6 in the latest version of Kotlin for android?

Tags: android, kotlin

im going through a kotlin coding course, but android studio wont take (random) as any acceptble code. Anybody know why?

```
val drawableResource = when (randomInt) {
            1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
            2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
            3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
            4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
            5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
            else -> R.drawable.dice_6
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you `Random` number `(1..6).random()` and you can use like this following :

```
val randomInt = (1..6).random()
val drawableResource = when (randomInt) {
            1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
            2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
            3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
            4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
            5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
            else -> R.drawable.dice_6
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this code inside then when clause , remember the 7 is exclusive so the number would be from 1-6

> Random.nextInt(1,7)

Comment: your welcome, you can upvote the answer , that would be helpful :)